# projection-plot country boundaries

Tags: python, matplotlib, projection, matplotlib-basemap

I use this code to plot a projection center over France:

```
from sys import argv

from numpy import array,histogram

from numpy import *

from math import *

from matplotlib.pyplot import *

from matplotlib.image import *

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, shiftgrid

from matplotlib import rcParams

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

import matplotlib.patches as patches

import matplotlib.path as path

import matplotlib.dates as dt

from numpy import linalg

def continents():

 lat=[]

 lon=[]

 for lig in file('24840.dat') :

   ligne=lig.split()


   if len(ligne[0]) > 1 :

     lon.append(ligne[0])

     lat.append(ligne[1])

   else:

     plot(lon,lat,'k',linewidth=0.5)

     lat=[]

     lon=[]

m = Basemap(width=12000000,height=9000000,projection='lcc',\
            resolution='l',lat_1=42,lat_2=52,lat_0=47,lon_0=8)

m.scatter(xlon,xlat,s=45,c=z,vmin=0,vmax=30,cmap=cm.get_cmap('jet', 45),edgecolors='None')

continents() 

m.drawcountries(linewidth=0.3)

m.drawstates(linewidth=0.3)

ax=colorbar()

xlim(-6,10)

ylim(42,52)


show()
```

I would like to see France boundaries but it doen not work...
Do you see what is missing?

Comment: I've added matplotlib and basemap tags.

Comment: Where do your xlon and xlat come from? Also your variable names suggest that your plotting lon/lat on a 'llc' projected grid. You probably need to convert the coordinates first. But since we dont have your data file, its impossible to replicate your problem.

Comment: xlon and xlat come from a file.

Comment: xlon and xlat come from a file. The data file have 4 columns: stations/lat/lon/data. Actually, I would like to plot my data on a grid in lat/lon. I am using Basemap because it seems more easy to drawn country boundaries, which is probably not the best way to do it.